# Zero Down Time with Sitecore Deployment

Tags: infrastructure

We have following production configuration

```
1) 1 CM & 4 CD's deployed on Azure which are Load balanced
2) MS SQL Azure
3) Master Slave configuration for Solr
4) No Sitecore XDB
5) Disaster recovery is not enabled
```

Can somebody help me to know how can we achieve Zero down time during deployment. Zero down time is required for CD's only for CMS its not required

Comment: One way to do this is to remove one by one CD server from the load balancer, deploy the code there and then put it back on the load balancer.

Comment: What about Sitecore  Items how do we keep code in sync with updated Templates & Renderings . If we publish before deploying code then other nodes with start throwing error due to mismatch of code & Sitecore Items

Comment: You could remove CD servers in batches - say do 2 at a time (assuming 2 CDs will be able to cope with the traffic). Update those 2 CDs, put them back in the LB, take the remaining 2 out, publish content from CM, update remaining CDs, put them back in LB.

Otherwise, you could consider updating server by server like @HishaamNamooya says, just not publish content until you're done deploying code to all 4 CDs (that's assuming you've coded defensively and won't get errors when code is updated but items aren't yet)

Comment: Thanks that's nice input  can we also  zero downtime if we have disaster recovery enabled or by using Blue Green deployment

Comment: Check out my answer hear. We used two environment with SQL compare. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/11370/sitecore-hosting-on-aws-with-blue-green-deployment-for-zero-downtime/11485#11485

Comment: Closing this. In general, you need to ask specific questions on this site, not "looking for general advise". I looked at your question history and you've been doing this a lot - 36 questions asked and _not a single one of them_ has been ticked as "answered". I think the Community Forums would be a better venue for your type of posts.